# fast-xml-parser dealing with large numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, fast-xml-parser

im trying to parse a XML with contains a value with big numbers, but is returning me :
~only examples~

```
2.9999903656804e+43
```

but the expected is:

```
2999999656804999999550999008999491999425661
```

my actual config is:

```
    const parser = new XMLParser({
        ignoreAttributes: false,
        numberParseOptions: {
            // com essa opção, caso o valor seja zero a esquerda, vira uma string.
            leadingZeros: false,
        },
    });
```

i read the documentation, but not found the explain.

Comment: JavaScript Numbers have a max precision of about 16 significant digits.  If you need exactly that number maybe use a string instead.

Comment: A conversation on this already exists on github, https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/issues/187 This might prove helpful.